# multiple regression analysis

Tags: c#, regression

I have to perform multiple linear regresson analysis and this is first time that i am working on this topic.
To put my problem,I have to compare a present game data with past stored game data and then predict the output. There can be n number of parameters on which the output can  depend.  I  have to  correctly compare the behaviour and predict the output. 
I need to implement the complete logic in c#,  can anyone suggest me a good approach to achieve this through pure coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer, rather a direction where you can start, as this question would be hard to answer without full understanding of your domain.

I would recommend getting started from [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Discovering-Statistics-Introducing-Statistical-Methods/dp/1847879071/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321876569&sr=1-1) and [SPSS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/uk/analytics/spss/). This will give you a bit of understanding which statistics do you really need to use, as there are many assertions and some verifications need to be done before any test. You can also start from Matlab, but I think it is more expensive and less user-friendly although a lot more powerful.

Once you know what kind of data you are dealing with (statistically speaking) you will then be able to find a correct test in SPSS for it. Once you happy with the test results, graphs and stats, you would need to find a proper implementation of that test in c#.

Comment: I am not having the permission to use any external tool to do this analysis. All what i'll be havng is data.

Comment: @Surbhi, well then you need to post a lot more details about the domain, such as, what kind of data you work with, how is it distributed, what kind of comparison you are doing, how the experiment is designed, how many variables etc.

Comment: To explain you the domain, I had to do  this analysis on a game  event. One dataset will comprise past data called 'comaparable event' and another dataset will be of present game. On the basis of previous data i need to compare,say for example,i want to predict the amount of a quantity to transfer (much like sales amount) in present game according to its consumption pattern in past game. Now consumption can depend upon factors like crowd gathered in a game,  weather etc. Confirming with all these factors a correct sales prediction is required. i  hope if this makes any sense ?

Answer (score -1):

Download a library that does it for you. For example, mathnet numerics ( https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics)

EDIT:
It seems I made a small error. The [MetaNumerics](http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/) library can do it for you. Here is the relevant [page](http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multivariate%20Samples&referringTitle=Documentation) in the documentation.

Comment: if you can suggest a practical demo on using this library, as i have no clue on how to begin with